# Restricting Field List Entries Based on User Role in Drupal 7

Tags: entities, users

I'm using the Field permissions module in Drupal 7 to restrict access to a list field I created based on the user's role and that works great.  But is there a way to restrict the content of that list based on the user role?

For example:

for user role 1, I want the custom field list to show:

Apple
Banana
Grape
Orange

for user role 2, I want the custom field list to show:

Apple
Grape

Answer (score 2):

There is a contributed module available in drupal.org 'Field Permissions' .

http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions  We can set the field  permission based on user role.

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook on hook_form_alter and modify options depending on the role. I see no non-programming way.

Comment: Asked/answered on SO - this answer treated more completely there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009716/restricting-field-list-entries-based-on-user-role-in-drupal-7#11875814